# Two jquery versions on one page where include method is used

Tags: jquery

I have a index.php page

It contains two other php files (nav.php and vertical_nav.php) and added by include method.

out of these two included php files, nav.php contains link for jquery 1.5.2 (link is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js)  and other vertical_nav.php contains jquery 1.9.0 (link is http://www.mydomain.com/lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js)

Now problem is when using these jquery, older version is not working. And I need it to work my navigation animation perfectly.

How to use two different versions of jquery ? I have googled it. I got solution as - use noconflict for this. But I am not getting how to use it and where to use it. Because my one jquery link is on nav.php and other newer 1.9.0 link is in vartical_nav.php and these two files are included on index.php.

Comment: You need to redesign your system so that you only ever have ONE version of jQuery no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the main problem is that you use 2 versions of the jQuery at the same time. Think about refactoring of your code and remove one of them.

In any case you can use such JS construction as one of possible solution:

```
// in file, where you include jquery 1.5.2:
var jQuery152 = jQuery.noConflict();

// in file, where you include jquery 1.9.0:
var jQuery190 = jQuery.noConflict();
```

After that you will have two global aliases for different jQuery libs. Then you can wrap your custom JS code in such construction (for example, if you want to use jQuery 1.5.2):

```
(function($) {
    // some code that relies on $ variable as on jQuery object
})(jQuery152);
```

Look at this article to get more info: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/